# HTTP Error 502.3 iis 10

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-server-2016

I got following error on iis 10 running an asp.net core application

```
HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.
```

and the following error at event viewer

```
Maximum rapid fail count per minute of '10' exceeded.
```

I also Have set stdout to true but there is no log

The following dotnet packages are installed on my computer

[image]

when i run the app using dotnet  myapp.dll on server and browsing localhost:5000 (enable log) for debugging after showing some normal debugging and information logs it waits and waits and nothing happen

here are dotnet packages that are installed on my server. also my server is joined on a domain if it is related running latest windows server 2016

[image]

my web.config is

```
 <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      <clear />       </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\NashrNegar.UI.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="C:\logs\" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="300000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>   </system.webServer>
```

what's the problem or any suggestion.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I have it as well

Answer (score 0):

Check your .net core version on the server. If the app was built on .net 1.1.2 and the server has .net core 2.0 it will not work. You will need to download the version the app was built.